# Using VBA to login to an Internet site

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to use VBA to open and login to an internet site.

I'm struggling with the HTML portion of my code. There is no "name" attribute in the HTML code. This is what is throwing me off.

References Checked:
Microsoft Internet Controls,
Microsoft Script Control 1.0,
Microsoft HTML Object Library

HTML for login text box:

```
<input class="ui-autocomplete-input" id="BIA_Login" autofocus="" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

HTML for password text box:

```
<input class="ui-autocomplete-input" id="BIA_Pass" type="password" autocomplete="off">



Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

    Const cURL = "xxxxxxxxxxx.com"
    Const cUsername = "xxxxxxx"
    Const cPassword = "xxxxxxx"

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim LoginForm As HTMLFormElement
    Dim UserNameInputBox As HTMLInputElement
    Dim PasswordInputBox As HTMLInputElement
    Dim SignInButton As HTMLInputButtonElement
    Dim HTMLelement As IHTMLElement

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate cURL

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Set doc = IE.document

    Set LoginForm = doc.forms(0)

    Set UserNameInputBox = LoginForm.elements("BIA_Login")
    UserNameInputBox.Value = cUsername

    Set PasswordInputBox = LoginForm.elements("BIA_Pass")
    PasswordInputBox.Value = cPassword
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getElementByID`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and use it directly against the Document element.

```
Set UserNameInputBox = doc.getElementById("BIA_Login")
UserNameInputBox.Value = cUsername

Set PasswordInputBox = doc.getElementById("BIA_Pass")
PasswordInputBox.Value = cPassword
```

Comment: See that's what I thought as well, but I kept getting a "Runtime Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" with the "Set UserNameInputBox = LoginForm.getElementById("BIA_Login")" line of code highlighted

Comment: @Davey - try late binding, dim everything as object. *(disclaimer, I mostly say that because that is what I typically do. I rarely work with the references)*. It could be that you have the wrong object types associated with the variables .... wait ... try `Set UserNameInputBox = doc.getElementById("BIA_Login")`

Comment: yeah when I highlight getElementById its not found in the HTMLInputElement class. I'll try that though

Comment: the Set UserNameInputBox = doc.getElementById("BIA_Login") solution worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Davey - you're welcome. Glad I caught it. :) I updated the answer.